# Is there a way in Google Sheets to extract a list of words found inside some paragraphs and sort it by count?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range of cells (i.e  A1:A25) in a google spreadsheet and each cell within this range has a text paragraph of 80+ words.
I would like to define a formula in cell B1 that returns 2 columns:

1. the first column (B:B) should return a list of words sorted by most used (top) to least used (bottom) in these paragraphs. Moreover, this list should exclude certain words such he/she/it/of/from/at/to/the/a/an etc
2. the second column (C:C) should return the count for each word listed in the cell to its left.

   Do you know of any solution?
   Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(z,index(regexreplace(tocol(split(textjoin(" ",1,lower(A:A))," ")),"\W$","")),
query(filter(z,iserror(xmatch(z,E:E))),"Select Col1,count(Col1) group by  Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Word_', count(Col1) 'COUNT_'"))
```

- *sample sentences are in Column_A*
- *excluded words list arranged in Column_E*

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!! I can't vote yet but I'd give it 10 points

Comment: I have a question. Could it be possible to achieve the same but only displaying results above a count of 2, for instance?

Comment: Try: `=let(z,index(regexreplace(tocol(split(textjoin(" ",1,lower(A:A))," ")),"\W$","")),
     x,query(filter(z,iserror(xmatch(z,E:E))),"Select Col1,count(Col1) group by  Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Word_', count(Col1) 'COUNT_'"),
     filter(x,index(x,,2)>2))`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. By the way, I have noticed that the"textjoin" function has the 50000 character limit. So this is an important limitation if we want to analyze large portions of texts. By any chance you any of any workaround?

Comment: Try: `=let(z,query(index(regexreplace(reduce(,sequence(counta(A:A)),lambda(a,c,{a;tocol(split(index(lower(A:A),c)," "))})),"\W$","")),"offset 1"),
     x,query(filter(z,iserror(xmatch(z,E:E))),"Select Col1,count(Col1) group by  Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Word_', count(Col1) 'COUNT_'"),
     filter(x,index(x,,2)>2))`

Comment: One further question if I may, I have noticed that in the returned list of words, those that finish with a special character, such as ó, à, é etc, this last character gets cut out. For instance, words such as "protecció" appear as "protecci". I think it must do with the regex expression in the formula. Any ideas what may cause this? Thanks again.

Comment: yes regex is added to remove non-word character at the end of the word. you may remove the regex part from the formula then